# cannot withdraw usdt out from metamask to bybit

Tags: metamask, usdt, meta-transactions

I have 115usdt in metamask and want to send to my bybit account but it always show Insufficient funds for gas. how should i do to fix this, im new in metamask

Answer (score 1):

> Since each Ethereum transaction requires computational resources to
> execute, each transaction requires a fee. Gas refers to the fee
> required to conduct a transaction on Ethereum successfully.

you need Ethereum in your sender address to pay for gas.

Answer (score 0):

In order to send any ERC20 token you must pay a fee to the network, but that fee is not paid in the ERC20 token, but in ether. You will need to send ether to your account and use that ether to send USDT to wherever you want. Once you're done with that you can transfer back the remaining ether.